# CKEditor: Create a Combo/DropDown of plugins in the toolbar

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm new with `CKEditor`. My goal is to decrease the number of buttons in the `toolbar` because the editor will be used in smartphones, so my idea was to organize `plugins` inside different `Combo`/`DropDown`. For example, I'd like to have a "Format" dropdown with all the formatting options.

I've seen several topics on how to create a custom `Combo`/`DropDown` plugin, but all of them implement new features. I want to be able to insert existing `plugins` inside my custom combo, is there any way to do that? I don't want to re-implement all the logic of the plugins inside my Combo.

Thanks!